# Is it viable to use await/async and threads simultaneously on one method?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, stream

I'm new to multithreading and I have a (probably) simple question about using threads and await/async simultaneously. I have a method which reads a TCP stream, then processes the response it received. It's called in a fashion showed below:

```
ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(ReadTCP);
Thread tt = new Thread(ts);
```

Is it viable to read the data from the stream asynchronously? Like in this code:

```
    private async void ReadTCP()
    {
        string responseData = string.Empty;  

        if(streamTCP.DataAvailable) 
        {
            responseData = await  readerTCP.ReadToEndAsync();

            // some code handling the response
        }
    }
```

Code edited with [MarioDS's help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45916311/7200978)

Comment: I don't think your streamTCP is thread-safe. This code will fail in some way.

Comment: I haven't locked it yet, but I know how to do it.

Comment: The locking might just nullify any threading you are trying to do.

Comment: This is about async I/O. You don't need threads. You don't want threads. And you certainly shouldn't use an `async void` method.

Answer (score 2):

Manually creating and manipulating threads is an advanced multithreading technique that requires a developer to **really** know what (s)he's doing (because memory fencing, synchronisation and marshalling between threads are all seriously advanced topics and easy to mess up). Thread-safety is hard.

If all you want is to improve responsiveness of your app, the async and await constructs that have been added to .NET a couple of years ago are perfect. They are not necessarily related to multithreading, as it is the underlying mechanism that decides whether new threads are created (and it's not always the case).

What you're doing is creating a thread and running the `ReadTCP` method on that thread.

You can just as easily fix `ReadTCP` so it returns `Task` (`async void` is really bad practice!) and then use it like this: `var response = await ReadTCP();` in an `async` method and it will give you what you want.

To run stuff in parallel while also running `ReadTCP`, create a variable for the task and `await` it later:

```
var readTask = ReadTCP();
DoOtherStuff();
AndMoreStuff();
AllAtOnce();
var response = await readTask;
DoSomethingWith(response);
```

By the way, you don't have to wrap async methods in `Task.Run`. Instead of doing: `Task.Run(() => FPXreaderTCP.ReadToEndAsync());`, just do `await FPXreaderTCP.ReadToEndAsync()`.

Comment: I don't need to store the response anywhere after the method finishes. It does some stuff with it, like writing to a database - that part is already multithread safe.

Comment: @FilipS still, make it return `Task` (the async equivalent of `void` in simple terms) and `await` it at an appropriate point in your code.